# Document library metadata navigation tree view collapses every time anything is clicked

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata, 2016

I have configured metadata navigation for existing document library on folder and one of the managed metadata column.

It shows tree view in left pane. Now **if I click any of the folder that folder is shown into view but tree view gets collapse and not showing that folder as selected** into tree view.

It's SharePoint 2016 on-premise.

I have created new library and made same configuration and it works for that library.I am unable to find any solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: does this help https://thechriskent.com/2012/05/09/changing-the-default-expansion-of-metadata-navigation-on-initial-page-load/ ?

Comment: Thank you Tiago. Yes it helps to show tree view as expanded. But the issue is it still does not maintain current selected item into tree view. Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: it's a pretty straight-forward feature. maybe you have some folder or view setting, javascript running, etc., that is messing it up. if you have a custom master page, try it with the ootb master and see if same thing happens. the fact that is works on a new lib could point out to a problem (or configuration) in your existing lib

Comment: Yes its ootb master page. You may be correct as I am also confused why it works for new lib and not for existing. I will post the solution if found.

Comment: One more thing - In existing library metadata navigation is working in SharePoint 2010. I have migrated site collection to SharePoint 2016 using metalogix tool. Is that something missing?

Comment: that tells you why it happened, but not what is the problem or how to fix it. sounds like you're getting close though. maybe contact metalogix support, or remove/re-add metadata navigation, compare both libraries, etc.

Comment: You are correct. I have to contact metalogix. Yes I already tried by removing/re-adding metadata navigation but no luck. Also compared all settings for both versions.